# SetUp and TearDown for entire run in Nunit?

Tags: nunit, integration-testing

I want to use NUnit to run GUI / integration tests.
What I would like to do is to initialize some custom reporting (from GUI-testing framework we use) before all tests and to run export of the reports after the whole suite has been run.

Is there some "super" setup method or practice to solve this problem?

I thought about running a special "TestFixture" before and after all other tests, but that is quite poor idea.
Another way would be to run some scripts afterwards but that doesn't solve the problem with pre-run initialization of logging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `[SetUpFixture]` attribute to instantiate a class before all tests are run. The constructor of this class will be called first. If this class implements `IDisposable`, then the `Dispose` method will be called after all tests are run.

Here's an example:

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class IntegrationSetUpFixture : IDisposable
{
    public IntegrationSetUpFixture()
    {
        // runs before all tests
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // runs after all tests
    }
}
```

Comment: As an alternative to using a constructor (for example, if FxCop complains about it), you can tag any arbitrary, public method in that `[SetUpFixture]` class with the `[SetUp]` attribute; similarly, any public method can be tagged with the `[TearDown]` attribute in place of needing to implement `IDisposable`.